# using an extra database after login in yii

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, authentication, yii

Does anyone know of a way in which I can add an extra database connection field to the yii configuration file after I've successfully logged in a user to my site?

We've got a global System Database where we configure our users and save a field with their database name.  I would like to create another connection to that database after authenticating the user.  Thus referencing it like Yii::app()->clientDB.  Is this possible?

Every client on our system have their own respective database with tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by this code (not tested, but should work):

```
$connection = new CDbConnection($dsn, $username, $password);
$connection->active = true;
Yii::app()->setComponent('clientDB', $connection);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.  In your config file it would look like:

```
'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=hostIP;port=3306;dbname=database1',
                    'class'=>'CDbConnection',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'username1',
        'password' => 'password1',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ),
            'db2'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=hostIP2;port=3306;dbname=database2',
                    'class'=>'CDbConnection',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'username2',
        'password' => 'password2',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ),
```

`db` would be the default database.  Whenever you want to switch you would write this in the controller:

```
$connection->Yii::app()->db2;
//then you would pass the connection into whatever you are using for your queries.
//For example for an raw SQL command:
$command=$connection->createCommand($sqlQuery);
$command->execute();
```